# Wakeup service in appcelerator titanium android and ios?

Tags: android, ios, titanium, appcelerator

I am looking for any way to wakeup a service every x minutes in `IOS` and `ANDROID` platforms

in `Java` i can do that using Alarm intent even if the app is closed , but in `Titanium` ( `Appcelerator` ) i could't find any solution, dose any one tried this before ?

if there is a hope in my request please share , it will be very much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this module for android using titanium

https://github.com/benbahrenburg/benCoding.AlarmManager

For iOS you can use the background service in iOS titanium

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.App.iOS.BackgroundService

Thanks

Comment: prefect , but my goal is for IOS more than android ^^

Comment: thank u I've tried it before , but when u close the app in ios the service is dead , so i need to wake it up again without starting the app , how !

Comment: Try not to stop the service as example has done and you would be good to go

Comment: i did , it say pause the application , so if the application stop the service will be killed , try it by ur self bro ,the example showing you how to run service if the app still alive